# Is there a C# library able to load html code and to define the header

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I have to download the html code from a website and parse it (unfortunately, parsing the html is the only way to get the necessary information). Of cause I could write my program using `WebRequest`, but I wonder whether there's a finished library for this.

I want to define the url and the header (cookies and POST-data) and would like to get the html code. It would be perfect if the library would return the answer-header as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to use `WebRequest` to do the communications (posting and retrieving data).  For parsing HTML, there is the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).  I have not used it myself though.

Comment: The HTML agility pack link leads to an msdn page about smalldatetime - I think you pasted the wrong link?

Comment: @all - thanks for the corrections. yes, trying to answer multiple questions at the same time will do that ;)

Comment: Not what I hoped to hear, but thanks for the reference to the HTML Agility Pack! Maybe I'll upload my script to BitBucket so it can be reused...